# cookbook_version root_dir in library

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a custom library and want to access the current cookbook from the cookbook_collection in the run_context, but it seems to be coming back null

I have

```
Chef::Log.info run_context.cookbook_collection['my_cookbook']
```

It prints

```
#<Chef::CookbookVersion:0x00000004d3f578>
```

But if I do

```
Chef::Log.info run_context.cookbook_collection['my_cookbook'].root_dir
```

where my_cookbook is the name of the current cookbook, I get nothing printed. How can I access the `root_dir` of the current_cookbook from my library?

Comment: Can you go into more detail on what you are trying to do? This is a _very_ internal API and changes in patch releases so using it is a recipe for pain.

Comment: trying to call powershell_out on a ps1 ile in my files/ directory without having to copy it out into a remote directory....and from a library where that ouldn't be possible

Comment: That is not supported and _will_ break in some releases. Use a `cookbook_file` resource first to copy it out to known location. This might mean your library helper code needs to be become a DSL extension or custom resource instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying down from the comment:

That is not supported and *will* break in some releases. Use a `cookbook_file` resource first to copy it out to known location. This might mean your library helper code needs to be become a DSL extension or custom resource instead.

Comment: that's a real bummer

Comment: The question is, what your actual problem is. Maybe you have a problem that can be solved better than you currently think.

Comment: I explained what my actual problem is in the comment to the question...if you have a better way to solve it, please do suggest. To restate - my problem is that I need to reference a powershell script in my files directory in a library in my cookbook